# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new on angular 2 and I'm trying to create a trivial module, but I get an error.

app.component.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Cronometro } from '../app/modules/cronometro';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  //directives:[Cronometro]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<h2>Cronometro</h2>
<cronometro></cronometro>
```

cronometro.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cronometro',
  templateUrl: 'app/modules/cronometro.html'
})

export class Cronometro {
  title = 'My First Angular App';

  public horas:number = 0;
  public minutos:number = 0;
  public segundos:number = 0;
  public started = null;

  constructor(){

  }

  start(){
    if(!this.started){
      this.started = true;
      console.log("start");
      this.started = setInterval(
        ()=>{
          this.segundos++;
          if(this.segundos == 60){
            this.minutos++;
            this.segundos = 0;
            if(this.minutos == 60){
              this.minutos = 0;
              this.horas++;
            }
          }
        }
        ,10);
    }
  }

  lapse(){

  }

  stop(){
    console.log("stop");
    clearInterval(this.started);
    this.started = null;
  }
}
```

cronometro.html

```
<button (click) = "start()" >Start</button>
<button (click) = "lapse()" >Lapso</button>
<button (click) = "stop()" >Stop</button>
<div >
  <p>{{horas}}:{{minutos}}:{{segundos}}</p>
</div>
```

and this the error message

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'cronometro' is not a known element:
1. If 'cronometro' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
</h1>
<h2>Cronometro</h2>
[ERROR ->]<cronometro></cronometro>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@4:0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'cronometro' is not a known element:
1. If 'cronometro' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
</h1>
<h2>Cronometro</h2>
[ERROR ->]<cronometro></cronometro>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@4:0
```

How would I make this a known element?

Comment: FYI you don't need type annotations on properties with initializers. Also, members are public by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the component to the `NgModule`, as error suggests:

> If 'cronometro' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

In your `app.module.ts`, add it to the declarations array:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, Cronometro ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I suggest you use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), because it will do this automatically when you use its commands to generate components/directives/etc.

Comment: This is poor advice as one should not be dependent on scaffolding tools, framework complexity notwithstanding.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I disagree. When you start learning something it's better not to be bogged down by trivial stuff, you are just wasting time instead of gaining knowledge. Unless you like coding in Notepad (;

Comment: I do not think the analogy is quite correct. The Angular CLI is generating code that you must be able to maintain.